# Нужна запятая и тире в случае уточнения?

Tags: пунктуация

> Танец "Пираты Карибского моря" профессионалы оценили очень высоко - он был удостоен диплома 3 степени.

Нужна ли запятая перед тире.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Танец "Пираты Карибского моря" профессионалы оценили очень высоко - он был удостоен диплома 3 степени.

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение,  второе предложение раскрывает содержание первого. Ставится только тире, которое заменяет классическое двоеточие.